# Временные таблицы

Tags: sql, table, expressions

> Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между обычной таблицей и временной?
>   И какая разница в целях применения одной и другой?

Comment: Временная таблица автоматически удаляется при закрытии соединения вместе с данными (хотя и может быть удалена явно).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов использования временных таблиц масса. Временные таблицы нужны в основном для хранения промежуточных данных в одной или нескольких процедур, транзакций. Основная идея вы держите данные актуальные на момент заполнения и по окончании процедуры, транзакции они вам не нужны. Сугубо личное мнение, прошу не ругаться сильно. Постоянные таблицы нужны для хранения актуальных на всё время данных и служат их источником для остальных.